# Totem (movie player) quits on suspend

Tags: 11.04, suspend-resume, totem

When I have a active window of movie player and suspend, then movie player quits.

Here is the setup:

- the window is seen on my screen.
- it doesn't matter if the video is or isn't playing.
- it's not a specific video or format.

How can I make movie player stop quitting?

[My laptop is an Asus 1201n](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1201N_Seashell/)

This is what happend when I played a movie, suspended, and when it woke up (10 seconds after) the laptop froze. That's why I had to take a picture with my iPhone instead of a screenshot.

[image: frozen error]

Comment: Can you provide more details? Run Movie Player from command line and paste the output after suspend?

Comment: report bug in launchpad

Comment: @shantanu well it isn't a bug apparently!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what your application is telling you (and from your hardware), it is probably that Totem/gstreamer runs out of memory when the system resumes from sleep (that is, it hits a point where it uses too much memory and is closed). I have experienced this problem with another netbook myself, and the reason behind it is simply that certain applications require large amounts of memory, but cannot get enough from the netbook's mediocre hardware without interfering with the stability of the system, and thus the applications are closed.

You would be surprised to know that games work just fine (you know this already as you have said), because of how they use the hardware. Instead of keeping a hold of large amounts of memory at a time, games often unload what they don't need to display at the time, and it is just that they do it "fast enough" that you don't notice lag.

Video players however (especially those without hardware acceleration) will run into problems as they not only dig through CPU cycles, but memory, which is required for seeking etc. Totem usually does a good job with video, but because of the way it uses memory, (gstreamer's fault) it doesn't do too well in situations where the memory is limited.

You can use the option to remember the video position in Totem, or try using VLC and enabling hardware acceleration :). Either way, it is not a good practice to suspend with a video player loaded, as it will take a lot of power to keep all of that memory fresh while you are on battery power and moving a system. Heavy consistent loads like that can actually shorten battery life (I killed a battery like that :).

/rant off, and I hope that answers your questions :).

Comment: wow 4 paragraphs I'm lucky if I manage 2 good answer